# how to prove that $ {P^{'}}$ has no real root?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $P(z)$  be a monic polynomial with complex coefficients with all
>   roots distinct and in $\{z \in C : \Im(z) \lt 0\}$.
>
> $(a)$ Prove that the sum of all the residues of $\frac{P^{'}}{P}$
>   is the degree of the polynomial $P$.
>
> $(b)$ Prove that  $ P^{'}$
>    has no real root.

My idea  was that  option $(a)$  as I take $f(z)$=$\frac{p^{'}(z)}{p(z)}$

$\deg(p(z))\ge \deg(p^{'}(z))+2$

**Residue theorem:** If $f$ is analytic in a domain except for isolated singularities at $a_1,\dots a_k$ then for any closed  contour $\gamma\in D$ on which none of the points $a_k$ lie, we have $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\sum_{1}^{k}n(\gamma;a_k)Res[f(z);a_k].$$

Here I don't know  how to proceed further.

For option $(b)$ if I  take even polynomial degree that $p(x) =x^2+1$ then it will not have real roots

As I don't know the actual proof. Please assist and help me.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: pliz help me,,anybody????

Comment: Part a) is an application of the so-called *argument principle* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), since $$\sum \operatorname{Res} (\frac{p'}{p}) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{p'}{p} \ dz = \text{Number of zeros of } p$$ which equals $\operatorname{deg}(p)$ by the fundamental theorem of algebra. For the contour $\gamma$, you can take an sufficiently large half circle in the lower half plane around the origin.

Comment: thanks  a lots complexFlo  and For part B) ????

Comment: There is a general result that says that the roots of $P'$ are contained in any half plane that contains the roots of $P$. Here, you are asked to prove a special case. Are you aware of that general result?

Comment: @ hANS ENGLER yes  ,i need proper way of proof both for option a) and optionb) ...otherwise my professor will not give marks in the exam?

Comment: Find the Gauss-Lucas theorem on wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is a residue theorem exercise.  For the second part, write $p(z) = \prod (z-a_i)$,  where the $a_i$ are the roots of $p$, possibly with repetition.  Then $p'(z)/p(z) = \sum \frac{1}{z-a_i} $.   Suppose $z$ is any complex number with $\Im(z) \ge 0$. Then
$$
\Im(p'(z)/p(z)) = \Im \left(\sum \frac{1}{z-a_i}\right) = \Im\left(\sum \frac{\bar z - \bar a_i}{|z-a_i|^2}\right).
$$
Now since $\Im(z) \ge 0$, it follows that $\Im(z - a_i) > 0\ $ for all $i$, hence $\Im(\bar z - \bar a_i) < 0$ for all $i$, hence $\Im(p'(z)/p(z)) \ne 0$, hence $p'(z) \ne 0$.

Note:  I just took the proof of the Gauss-Lucas theorem from the wikipedia article, and took a short cut appropriate to the special case.

Comment: thanks a lots fredgoodman